# How to change font size of Nav Bar on back pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue

Okay this is a problem that's been frustrating me for a bit. I have two screens in a nav controller one's bar needs to be a big font size (bigFontVC), one needs to be a small font size (smallFontVC).

I go from bigFontVC to smallFontVC with a segue. The smallFontVC's viewDidLoad is:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.setToNormalFont() 
}
```

and bigFontVC´s viewDidLoad is:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.setToSmallFont() 
}
```

the resize works perfectly from the segue from bigFontVC to smallFontVC.

Now going from smallFontVC to bigFontVC is more difficult. I know the bigFontVC doesn't go out of load so viewDidLoad doesn't get called. Now I'm trying to work out where to put my function

```
    self.navigationController?.setToNormalFont()
```

to resize BigFontVC's navBar font size.

The problem is the places I first thought to put this function cause the navigation bar to do the font switch but it shows first only half the title. e.g 'GAM' and then a split second later 'GAMES'. It just doesn't look good to have this on every change. As this didn't happen going from bigFontVC to smallFontVC i'm sure I can make it not happen going the other way, but that is where i'm asking for help.

Below are the places I have tried to put that function which cause the title to flash and not change smoothly.

In BigFontVC the following place:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     self.navigationController?.setToNormalFont()
```

}

In SmallFontVC the following place:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setToNormalFont()
}
```

This I know is a weird problem it may be something much deeper in navigation controller that I don't know. I was thinking maybe somehow overriding the back button to make it perform a segue as I know with a segue there wasn't this problem. Any help would be appreciated even if it's just to tell me it's not possible.

---

Also in case it helps this is my navcontroller function:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    func setToNormalFont(){
        setFont(as:  UIFont(name: "futura", size: 19)!)
    }
    func setToSmallFont(){
        setFont(as:  UIFont(name: "futura", size: 16)!)
    }
    func setFont(as font: UIFont){
        let titleAttributes = [
            NSFontAttributeName: font
        ]
        self.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = titleAttributes
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622601-setneedslayout